# If $5\mid n(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$, why can $n$ have the form $5k$, $5k+1$, $5k+2$, $5k+3$, $5k+4$? Why not $5k+5$, $5k+6$, etc?

Tags: divisibility

If $5 \mid n (n^2 + 1) (n + 1) (n - 1)$, why can $n$ be of the form $5k$, $5k + 1$, $5k + 2$, $5k + 3$, $5k + 4$? Why can't it be $5k + 5$, $5k + 6$,  etc?

Comment: Consider division $n$ by $5$. It gives some remainder $0\le m\le 4$ and quotient $k$, thus $n=5k+m$. You may as well consider $m\ge 5$, but considering $0\le m<5$ is sufficent (exhaustive).

Comment: If $n=5k+5$ then $n=5K$ with $K=k+1$, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If $n = 5k+5 = 5(k+1)$ then let $m=k+1$ and $n=5m$.

Similarly, if $n = 5k+6 = 5(k+1)+1$, again let $m=k+1$ and $n=5m+1$.

The idea is, when you divide $a \div b$, then the remainder must be one of $0,1,\ldots, b-1$. Otherwise, you did not divide correctly.